# Python Selenium Alert Authentication Trouble

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, authentication, alert

I am trying to access a website that requires a login thru an alert box such as the one below:

[image]

I have tried to look up many different ways to do this and they dont seem to work. what i have tried are listed below:

1. Didnt work and gave me the same login alert.

   ```
   start_url = 'http://username:password@example.com'
   agent.get(start_url)
   ```
2. Keep getting an error message saying "NoAlertPresentException: Message: no alert open"

   ```
   start_url = 'http://www.example.com'
   alert = agent.switch_to_alert()
   alert.send_keys("username")
   alert.send_keys("password")
   ```
3. Get an error saying webdriver has no attribute "switchTo"

   ```
   start_url = 'http://www.example.com'
   agent.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("username")
   ```

I have to use Chrome because of the versions of IE and Firefox I have and can get, do not support the functions in the site

Comment: Hello @harry-singh Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having this exact same issue for some time now - with my end goal being to do this *headless* (in the background without visually launching an instance of Chromedriver).

**Non-Ideal Solution 1**:
I first used a library called **pynput** to automatically type the credentials in to the alert box and click the ok button, it was pretty simple to get working but:

- still didn't work headlessly
- I had to be focused on the browser or it would type the credentials elsewhere

This worked great in the meantime as everywhere I looked online it seemed like there was nothing I could do to overcome authentication alerts headlessly...

I'm a relative beginner (started programming <1 year ago) so perhaps I just wasn't looking in the right places!

**I've now solved this issue though like so:**

First I logged in to the alert as normal on Chrome while monitoring the Network section of devtools to get a good look at the GET request for the protected page [screencap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWylj.jpg):

Upon seeing that the Authorization was Basic (this will work for Bearer too) I tested just copying the same request in Postman with this header and it worked! Now if only there was a way to make http requests from Selenium???

I first tried the library **selenium-requests** (which didn't work for me: I got the same error as this person https://github.com/cryzed/Selenium-Requests/issues/33
This library seems absolutely excellent and exactly what I needed, I just don't currently have the know-how to get past firewalls/whatever was stopping me at this stage...

What eventually worked for me was the library **selenium-wire**. I followed this guide https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#intercepting-requests-and-responses to have the webdriver navigate to the protected page as normal, but intercept the request and add the Authorization header before sending it :) now this works for me totally headlessly. Granted, this won't work on more secure websites but I hope it helps someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is Pythoncode**
>   Problem with alert boxes (especially sweet-alerts is that they have a
>   delay and Selenium is pretty much too fast)

An Option that worked for me is: (just exchange the button click in the end with whatever action you want to have)

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="sweet-alert showSweetAlert visible"]')
        break
    except:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000)

confirm_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="confirm"]')
confirm_button.click()
```

Note to 2: Here is probably the error due to the alert taking more time to load than the single elements (such as username, etc.)
Note to 3.: I think it should be switch_to