# Can’t hide the browser modal window using Selenium+Python after updating the chromedriver to version 119

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cicd

I need your help so much! I have autotests written using Selenium+python+pytest in Gitlab CI\CD. After updating Chrome and, accordingly, the Chrome driver to version 119, the pop-up modal browser window was no longer blocked using the specified webdriver options on the registration page. To work with page elements, you need to cancel it or block its appearance. So, due to the modal window, the test does not see the elements of the registration page. In version 118 of Chrome, the tests worked without problems with the following options:

```
def driver() -> WebDriver:
    print("\nStart browser for test..")
    options=Options()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
    options.add_argument('--disable-translate')
    browser = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub',
        options=options)
    yield browser
    print("\nQuit browser")
    browser.quit()
```

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:3.10.0
default:
  tags:
    - almalinux8
    - common
    - dev-runner05
    - devops
    - docker
stages:
  - test

.job_template:
  before_script:
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - pytest -s -v --tb=native 

e2e:remote:chrome:
  extends: .job_template
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Modal window of Chrome browser looks like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJtV6.jpg)

So I tried to use this code for closing modal window:

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
```

and this:

```
alert=driver.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss()
```

But these codes don't do anything. I also try to use autotests modul pyautogui and keyboard, but they doesn't work on Gitlab CI\CD, only on local starting Chrome browser. With pyautogui it's CI\CD error:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/builds/luxms-bi/luxms-bi-data/Autotests/Sales/conftest.py'.
Autotests/Sales/conftest.py:31: in <module>
    import pyautogui
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py:246: in <module>
    import mouseinfo
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py:223: in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/os.py:679: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'DISPLAY'
```

and with Keyboard it's error:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dumpkeys'`

Comment: This looks like basic authentication popup, which you have to handle to proceed. Meaning you have to enter username/password. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70559122/10413416

Comment: The problem was solved by adding:
options.add_argument('--headless')

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved by adding:

```
options.add_argument('--headless')
```